# File Geodatabase XY Resolution and XY Tolerance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, topology, resolution, tolerance

At [Limiting XYZ Geometry Drift](http://gisintelligence.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/limiting-xyz-geometry-drift/) I found the description of XY Resolution and XY Tolerance in ArcGIS.

My cadastral data in shapefile format have an accuracy of 1 cm. If I want to work with my data in a File Geodatabase should I use XY Tolerance 0,01 m and XY resolution 0,001 m ( http://goo.gl/uqDrG ) or are those values improper for topology matters and so on?

Answer (score 5):

**x,y tolerance**

Your data has an accuray of 1 cm. With this accuray I would not use a x,y tolerance of 1 cm. During feature processing operations coordinates that fall within the x,y tolerance will snap to the same shared coordinate location. The maximum distance a coordinate could move to its new location is the square root of 2 times the x,y tolerance. If you use a x,y tolerance of 1 cm the maximum distance a coordinate could move is 1.4 cm. So the coordinates will move more (1.4 cm) than the accuray (1.0 cm) of our data. This image from [esri help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000001v000000) shows how coordintes will move:

[image: tolerance]

I would use a tolerance of 0.1 cm.

**resolution**

The x,y tolerance should be coarser than the resolution. In ArcGIS the default value esri uses for the x,y tolerance is 10 times x,y resolution. If you use a tolerance of 0.1 cm you shold use a resulution of 0.01 cm.

(It is possible to use every value as tolerance and resolution (e.g. 0.5, 0.12345, 0.99 ...). But I like to use a resolution of 1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 ... This makes it more easier that the resulution grid of different projects (with different resolutions) fits together.)

Summary: I would use a x,y tolerance of 0.001 m and a resolution of 0.0001 m.